# Combining 2 different attributes in a record to find whether a set

Tags: sql

I have a table that has the following columns,
RecID, RegionID, LanguageID

I want to find sets based on RegionID and languageID. The way I want to relate them is a bit complicated though. Maybe the best way to describe it is through example. Each set should include any records that relate through RegionID or LanguageID. I would like create a new column SetID that will distinguish which set each RecID is in.

I would like the result set to look like:

```
RecID, SetID
```

As an example if I had a table with 5 records:

```
RecID, RegionID, LanguageID
1, A, Eng
2, B, Eng
3, B, Spa
4, C, Spa
5, D, Fre
```

That would represent 2 sets. The desired output would be:

```
RecID, SetID
1, 1
2, 1
3, 1
4, 1
5, 2
```

The reasoning goes as follows. RecID 1 relates to RecID2 through a matching LangID. RecID 2 relates to RecID3 through a matching regionID. RecID 3 relates to recID 4 through a matching languageID. Since those are all related, they are in the same set. RecID5 does not relate to any other records so it is in its own set.

Comment: What SQL technology are you using?

Comment: It is an Oracle server,

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like :

```
SELECT t.RecId, (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                   FROM table t1 
                                   WHERE t1.LanguageID = t.LanguageID AND t.RegionID <> t1.RegionID
                                  ) 
                      THEN 1 ELSE 2 
                END) AS SetID
FROM table t;
```

For this version `1` for same group & `2` for different group.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh. I am looking for a more generalized solution though. Also, I don't think this works for the problem space. This would not put RecID 1, 2, and 3 all in the same set.